# Octomap messages in rosbridge_1 to 2

Tags: ros-melodic, ros2, octomap, rosbridge

I am using Ros 2 but want to map the environment with Octomap. I use the rosbridge between Ros 2 (rolling) and Ros melodic. However,  `octomap_msgs/Octomap`  is not a default message. I know it is possible to create custom messages, but as I understand, it is for messages that do not exist in Ros 1 and Ros 2. How can I add  `octomap_msgs/Octomap`  messages to the bridge? If it is in the same way as the custom messages (https://github.com/lidiaxp/ros1_bridge/blob/01708c910130dbcd44ec9b39785d700ad4bb9b4b/doc/index.rst#how-does-the-bridge-know-about-custom-interfaces 2), how this code works  `colcon build --packages-select ros1_bridge --cmake-force-configure` ? It would work similarly if I already have the messages (in ros folders, for example).